# Abstracting Calls to Android Intents

Tags: android

So I've got to the point where my Android Activities and Fragments are getting a little messy. And I'd like to apply some good coding practice. However, every time I come up with a good SOLID design, Android gets in the way!

As a concrete example, I have a fragment that allows a user to update their details (name, email etc). It also allows them to take a picture to use as their profile picture.

I want to move this "picture taking" code out into a separate interface. Let's call it `PhotoTaker`. I then want a class called `AndroidPhotoTaker` that will implement this interface to start the correct Intent and return the filename of the picture taken.

```
public interface PhotoTaker {
    Uri capturePhoto();
}

public class AndroidPhotoTaker implements PhotoTaker {
    private Context _context;

    @Inject
    public AndroidPhotoTaker(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri capturePhoto() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(_context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = new File("some/path/to/a/file");

            Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(_context, _context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            _context.startActivity(takePictureIntent);
            return photoUri;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Assume that the correct context gets injected in via Dagger2.

My problem is that I can no longer call `startActivityForResult()` as I did in the fragment. And thus I no longer have the `onActivityResult()` callback to process the result. The only thing I can really find is `_context.startActivity()`, but that doesn't seem right.

And there's no callback -- I want to be able to get any extra data from these intents in the future.

How have other people solved this problem? What's the general solution here? i.e. how do people abstract away Android intent calls that have callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion abstracting away the calback handling makes the coding far **too complicated:**  you have to implement your own 
Activity-Baseclass that catches calls that android makes to onActivityResult() and forward these calls to your self-defined 
IOnActivityResult interface that your hosting activity must implement.

Instead of this you can create a helper class with static method that creates and analyses Intents.

```
public class MyPhotoTakerClientActivity extends Activity {

    private void onTakePhotoClicked() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = PhotoTakerHelper.createIntent("some/path/where/to/store/the/resultfile.jpg");
        if (PhotoTakerHelper.canProcess(this, takePictureIntent)) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TakePhotoID);
        } else {
            ... error processing
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                    final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case TakePhotoID :
                Uri uri = PhotoTakerHelper.getPhotoUri(intent);
                showPhoto(uri);
                break;
            ...
```

In my apps all Activities have a static method showActivity that receives all parameters that can travel from the calling activity to sub-activity:

```
public class FotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    public static void showActivity(Activity context, GalleryFilterParameter filter, 
                      QueryParameter query, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FotoGalleryActivity.class);

        if (filter != null) {
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FILTER, filter.toString());
        }

        if (query != null) {
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUERY, query.toReParseableString());
        }

        if (requestCode != 0) {
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        } else {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The calling activity does not need to know how the parameters travel. All it needs is a call to `FotoGalleryActivity.showActivity(getActivity(), getFilter(), null, ID_GALLERY);`

Comment: I guess this would prevent any sort of mocking for unit testing? i.e. I don't want to start an Intent for a unit test. 

Although I've given up on trying to unit test with Android for now.

Comment: I agree, static methods makes unittest-mocking impossible, But since i donot "unittest" android activity interaction it doesn-t matter for me. feel free to make the code non-static